# jQuery each returns [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, append, each

My problem is that the html variable returns something like this: [object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object], instead of the  elements.

What should i do different?

```
var html = '';
$.each(data.response, function(index, value) { 
    var tr = $('<tr>');
    var tr_data = '<td>asd</td>';
    html += tr.data('trackinfo',value).html(tr_data);   
});

$(target).html(html);
```

Comment: Can you please post what the `data` variable contains. I'm guessing JSON?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you're setting the data on the `tr` and then filling it with your html, but still concatinating an object, which converts it to a string... aka

```
"[object Object]"
```

Not exactly sure what you're after but you might try changing this...

```
html += tr.data('trackinfo',value).html(tr_data);
```

To this...

```
html += tr.data('trackinfo',value).html(tr_data).html();
```

Comment: Thanks, its working now, however, sadly i can't reach the trackinfo data, .date('trackinfo') returns undefined:(

Answer (score 2):

By default, Jquery creates objects not html mark-up. To get html you should to call html() method.

Here is working code:

```
var html = '';
$.each(data.response, function(index, value) { 
    var tr = $('<tr>');
    var tr_data = '<td>asd</td>';
    html += tr.data('trackinfo',value).html(tr_data);   
});

$(target).html(html);
```