# jQuery function returning [object Object] after concatenating string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a menu with the following menu structure:

```
<nav>
   <ul>

   </ul>
</nav>
```

With this function I'm trying to copy all titles from my page to the menu.

```
$('.pagetitle').each(function() {

  var titles = $(this).contents().clone();
  $('nav ul').html('<li><a>' + titles + '</a></li>');

});
```

It works just fine without adding the li and a tags but predefining the html tags in my menu, but I have to create them thru this function since I can't know how many titles there will be on the page.

I have read this post: [jQuery each returns [object Object]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263813/jquery-each-returns-object-object) and got a little wiser, but it did not solve my problem. If anyone could explain me why this is happing, that would be great!

Comment: What do the `.pagetitle` elements look like?

Comment: `titles` is a jQuery object with string representation equals to `[object Object]`, maybe you want instead: `var titles = $(this).contents().clone().prop('outerHTML');` or `var titles = $(this).contents().clone().html();`. You just forgot in question to tell what you are looking for

Comment: Alternatively you can use `.wrap()` to wrap the contents with new containers.

Comment: @pointy @A. Wolff Thank you for replying. The page title elements are `<h3>` tags with content.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Maybe, not sure what expecting here

Comment: Thank you all or replying, learned a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply use `$(this).html()`

```
$('.pagetitle').each(function() {    
  var titles = $(this).html();
  $('nav ul').html('<li><a>' + titles + '</a></li>');

});
```

Comment: I've accepted your answer because it's the most straightforward and close to my code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As @A.Wolff said the problem is `titles` is a jQuery object.

I would use .map() like

```js
//to initialize the value
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  $('<div />', {
    text: i,
    'class': 'pagetitle'
  }).appendTo('body')
}


//solution
$('.pagetitle').map(function() {
  //use .map() to create new `li` element for each `.pagetitle` element
  return $('<li />', {
    //set the pagetitle's content as its value
    html: $(this).contents().clone()
  }).get();
  //append the new `li` elements to `nav ul`
}).appendTo('nav ul')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul></ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, +1 for showing me an expert level of doing this. I've accepted sesem's answer because it's most straightforward and close to my code.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of each item in `.each()` function, simply use `$(this).html()`. Furthermore, you should use `.append()` instead of `.html()`.

So, your code should be:

```
$('.pagetitle').each(function () {
    var titles = $(this).html();
    $('nav ul').append('<li><a>' + titles + '</a></li>');
});
```

You can check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qczewnt9/1/)